# Can I make a plane renderable but not effect the light in the scene?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

I want to add in a plane into blender with an image on it. I want the image to render out into the scene but I don't want the plane to effect the the light in the scene. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: disable the Diffuse option in the Properties panel > Object > Visibility?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Go to your object properties and in Visibility>Ray Visibility, uncheck "Shadow"
[image]